# Background colour setting missing from Windows Sticky-Notes

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, sticky-notes

Recently I had to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch on a new drive.  This incidentally resolved a different problem I was having with the Sticky-Note widgets.  But I realized that now the `...` is missing from the widget menu-bar, so I can no longer choose the background colour for any of my sticky notes.  I know notice the feature is suddenly missing on my Windows 7 machine at work. So I wonder if this has been caused by a recent Windows Update. Has Microsoft (either intentionally or accidentally) removed this feature from Sticky Notes? Is there a Windows configuration option or registry setting to restore this?

[image]

On my Win 10 machine I have tried using the "Reset" feature for the app (via ***Start > Settings > System > Apps & Features***) but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion was indeed an attempt to use the "Reset" feature built in to try and resolve the issue. However, you may have actually reinstall sticky notes itself.

> **Reinstall Sticky Notes app using PowerShell**
>
> 1. Open Start Menu or Taskbar Search and type PowerShell.
> 2. Right-click on Windows PowerShell and select “Run as Administrator”.
> 3. In PowerShell window, type or paste the following command and then press Enter key from the keyboard.
>
> Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers
>
> 4. Look for Sticky Notes entry and once you find it, copy its PackageFullName by selecting it and then using Ctrl + C hotkey.
> 5. Execute the following command to uninstall Sticky Notes app from your computer.
>
> Remove-AppxPackage PackageFullName
>
> From the above command, replace PackageFullName with the actual
>   PackageFullName which you have already copied in the previous step.
>
> 6. Now, Sticky Notes from your Windows 10 operating system has been removed successfully.
>
> Close the PowerShell.
>
> 7. Open Windows this link and click Get the app button to open Windows store.
> 8. From the Windows Store, click Free button to reinstall Sticky Notes app on your computer.
>
> **Option two:**
>
> Reinstall Sticky Notes app in Windows 10 using IObit Uninstaller
>
> 1. Download IObit Uninstaller.
> 2. Launch the program and from the left pane, click Windows app.
> 3. Right-click on Sticky Notes app to uninstall and select Uninstall option.
>
> Once again install the Sticky Notes app from Windows official store.

You may view the method [here](https://routerunlock.com/reset-reinstall-sticky-notes-windows-10/), which is what I listed above.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore the background colour (`...`) menu **in Windows 10** applying an software update in the Microsoft Store.

Open the Microsoft Store app, search for "Microsoft Sticky Notes". On the app page, click the **Update** button.

**But I have not resolved the problem on my Windows 7 machine so far.**